# How to set a custom Return-Path when sending emails using Mail::factory('smtp',

Tags: php, email, return-path

I'm trying to send emails that will bounce to an address specified by me, different from the address it's sent from.

the code i'm using to send the emails is

```
$headers = array (
    'From' => $emailAdr
    'To' => $emailDest,
    'Subject' => $subject,
);                                      
$hdrs = $mime->headers($headers);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
        array ('host' => 'ssl://'.$emailServer,
               'auth' => true,
               'port' => '465',
               'username' => $emailUser,
               'password' => $emailPass));

$mail = $smtp->send($emailDest, $hdrs, $body);
```

I searched all over the internet for a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$headers = array (
    'From' => $emailAdr
    'To' => $emailDest,
    'Subject' => $subject,
    'Return-path' => 'return@path.com',
);
```

But, different mail servers translate return path by their own rules (it's just will use `From`, `Reply-to` or `X-Return-Path` etc

Comment: I just tried all of them. First, even when I set the FROM header it's still replaced with the sender's address. Setting the Reply-to header will still send the bounce email to the sender address but will also screw up replies in some email clients (for example thunderbird will reply to the Reply-to address, but google won't). Return-path and X-Return-Path don't seem to make a difference in any of my tests.

Comment: Yeah, it's some mail server's `magic` (tag:irony)!!! Google use only from field, and it's can't be override at many mail servers (